# how neo4j follows ACID properties?

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to know how neo4j follows ACID properties. I have gone through official doc and some blogs, but none of them could explain properly.

I wanted to achieve the ACID properties for my neo4j graphDB:
A- Atomicity, 
C- Consistency, 
I- Isolation, 
D- Durability.

Comment: Neo4j is ACID per default, and this behaviour can't be removed. So you have nothing to do to be ACID with Neo4j, just use it :)

Comment: Are you referring to atomic operations such as atomically incrementing a property, ensuring no race conditions? Neo4j is an ACID database, but there are opportunities between a read and a write (locks are taken on writes) when race conditions can occur. There are some solutions you can use, if this is what you need.